# To display Profile name of the related user in related list

Tags: profile, user

I have a team member object. Team member have a master detail relationship with "Team" object and a lookup relationship with "User" object. The lookup field for User object is labelled as "Related User" and its API name is "Users__c".

I need a formula field to display the profile name of the user object(lookup relationship - Users__c) in team member object . The name of this formula field is "User Profile".

I could display the profile name of the "User__c" in team object as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

But the problem I face is, the profile name when displayed in related list, i.e when team member is shown as related list in "Team" detail page of a record, it is shown as "PT1" as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Formula I used for "User Profile" field is :-  Users__r.Profile.Name. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot, i can see for one of the team members (0129), the name of the profile is coming up properly(Analytics Cloud integration user)

Are you sure the profile name is different from PT1?(if it was wrong, it shud nt have come for the last team  member also)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue for Value of Profile.Name used in custom formula fields differs from UI and Lightning / API context.

You can check [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000181gKQAQ)

Workaround
As per above Article: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_creating_cross_object_notes.htm&language=th

You could use the Case() function to 'translate' the values in the Formula Field considering the

Example: IF 
(OR 
(LastModifiedBy.Profile.Name = "Standard User", LastModifiedBy.Profile.Name = "PT2"), 
"Standard", "Not Standard")

You can obtain the full list of matching values between Internal/External labels here: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_understanding_global_variables.htm&language=es_M_2

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. But even this does not work for me.
The related list looks like this.

[image]

And detail page looks like this

[image]